# Creating and deploying new Heroku applications with a Rails application hosted on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku

I have a rails application running on heroku. I would like to make that application to create & deploy other applications on heroku.

Since the Cedar stack allows writing to the filesystem I can generate the files needed for the new application. My question is how to issue the "heroku create" and "git push heroku master" commands for deployment.

Is there any gems out there / can I use the heroku CLI in heroku together with the ruby system call?

Comment: Ok ... there is the 'ruby-git' gem to create & update git repositories inside a Rails app,

and, 

the heroku gem has an API https://api-docs.heroku.com/apps which can be used to create new apps on the fly

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything that you need to do Heroku wise with the Heroku gem.  Bear in mind though that this will need credentials to authenticate, so you'll need to be happy with storing these in the applications config.

From a git point of view, use ruby-git.

It's probably worth looking at making whatever it is you're making multi-tenanted so you don't have to worry about this problem, and also won't have to worry about hundreds of applications to maintain (updates, bugfixes and the like)